# Webgl - dynamic mouse position

Tags: javascript, webgl, glsles

I am playing around with `webgl` copied from [this page](http://raymarching.com). I want to use mouse to control the light position.

If I just send the static value from `js` to `fragment shader` it will work:

```
mouseLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "mouse");
gl.uniform2f(mouseLocation, 0,0);
```

I have a function to update the mouse position:

```
function updateMousePosition(e){
    console.log(e.pageX);
    mousex = e.pageX;
    mousey = e.pageY;
}
```

which is called when mouse move:

```
canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', updateMousePosition, false );
```

then send the mouse position to `fragment shader` every frame:

```
gl.uniform2f(mouseLocation, mousex,mousey);
```

After that I will get the mouse position from `fragment shader`:

```
uniform vec2 mouse;

void main(void) {
    //mp - mouse position
    vec2 mp = vec2(mouse.x / resolution.x, 1.0 - mouse.y / resolution.y);

    //lp depend on mp
    vec3 lp = vec3(mp.x, mp.y, -1.0);

    //other calculation ...
}
```

it did not work. 
But when I send down static value from `console.log` in `updateMousePosition(e)`:

```
gl.uniform2f(mouseLocation, 679, 590);//number taken from console.log
```

it work.

I am not sure what is not working but I suspect is the format or type of the number, `js` is not strictly type but `glsl` is.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to show more code. There's nothing wrong with what you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly decided to put this answer (edited).

As Gman commented, there is apprently nothing wrong with your code. Technically, this should work. However you pointed out a real tricky aspect of the WebGL/Javascript couple compared to OpenGL: The typage. And due to how Javascript variables works, you easily generate strange bugs.

Imagine this absurde situation:

```
var x = 55;
var y = 128;

// some code here...

x = "blah"; // oups !

// some code here...

gl.uniform2f(mouseLocation, x, y);
```

With C, C++ or other strong typed language, such absurdity is almost impossible to do (this is possible through pointers, but this is another subject), because the compiler forbid it stricly and throw an error. But in javascript, there is no problem, and in this case, the `x` number variable becomes an string variable, and when passed to WebGL, it become `NaN`. If you don't have correctly tracked the `x` variable, you will search long time why this does not work.

All WebGL functions only accepts typed data in the last stage, because last stage is the GPU, and GPU is low-level. That is, even if you pass a pure Javascript Number variable to a WebGL function, this Javascript variable WILL BE converted to typed data before. But the fact is that Javascript will never throw an error about wrong variable types: It converts it (cast) to typed data, and even if what you attempt to do is absurd, it will never warn you, it will transform non-convertible data into 'NaN`.

Fortunately, to avoid any ambiguity, WebGL comes with a bunch of new Javascript objects: the Typed Arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/TypedArray

With typed Arrays, you can know within your javascript code what data is stored, and so what data will be sent to the GPU before you send it. 
That is, you can use typed array to convert (cast) Javascript variables into known typed data before it is sent to GPU.

```
var mousePos = new Float32Array(2);

function updateMousePosition(e){
  mousePos[0] = e.pageX;
  mousePos[1] = e.pageY;
}

// do something

console.log(mousePos);
gl.uniform2fv(mouseLocation, mousePos);
```

In the above example, the variables `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` are directly converted into WebGL compatible typed data. That way, if you now print the `mousePos` variable using `console.log` you will see what will be really sent, as it, to WebGL. For debug purpose, you can put the `console.log` just before the call to `gl.uniform2fv` to ensure nothing wrong happened "out of view".

In this example, if any data was wrongly converted, you will see something like `NaN`, `NaN` in your output log, so you know that you have to search somewhere a mistake in your code.

Comment: I actually kind of figured out what happen but forgot to update the answer. You are right in your answer. However, my solution is similar but simpler. I just declare and initialize the variable like `var x = 0.0` then everything work like a charm. Anyway, I accept your answer for the details explanation.